# Como configurar mi aplicación para que se ejecute de manera automática cuando abra el .exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

He creado una aplicación de escritorio la cual obtiene registros de una api al seleccionar un rango de fecha con unos datapicker, lo único que se debe hacer es dar clic en el botón "Invoiced" y agrega los datos al mi BD.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], me gustaría saber si se puede ejecutar de manera automática cuando abra o ejecute el .exe,realice ese procedimiento, si se puede me podrían apoyar en como se podría realizar o donde investigarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Como podrias configurar que cosa? que haga algo tu aplicacion al abrirse? bueno, ya hace muchas cosas, por ejemplo abrir un formulario.. en el codigo de apertura del formulario, podes hacer todas las cosas que quieras...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: C# no es mi campo, pero entiendo que en Visual Studio habra alguna opcion para compilar, y seguramente deje el fichero .EXE en alguna parte; al compilar fijate bien en los mensajes de log ya que seguramente informen donde se ha dejado el .EXE

Comment: En el constructor del Form, luego de InitializeComponent() llamas a la misma función que llama el evento del Invoiced

Answer (score 0):

Me ayudo mucho el comentario de Yussef, ya lo pude resolver, anexo código de como lo hice por si le es útil para alguien mas.

```
    public frmMain()
    {
       
        InitializeComponent();
        frmMain_Load(dtp1, null);
        btnRequest_Click(Global.date1, null);
    }
```

Yo mando llamar primero **frmMain_Load**(dtp1, null) y posterior **btnRequest_Click**(Global.date1, null) ya que tengo que obtener la primera fecha por que si no lo coloco, me trae el dia de hoy y no funciona.

```
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtp2.Value = DateTime.Now;
        dtp2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dtp2.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

        dtp1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20);
        dtp1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dtp1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    }
```

Comment: No uses imagenes!!!! pon el codigo como texto!

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas para publicar el código _como texto, con formato_. Subir capturas de pantalla de código [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.